# radixSort java Implement using distribution sort

Tags: algorithm, sorting, distribution, radix

[RadixSort using distribution sort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8ko6.png)

I need some help to implement Radix Sort algorithm using the distribution counting sort, i know what i need to do but i don't know how.

below you can find my code, i'm having trouble to associate the less significant digits to the String where those digits come from in order to sort the input array.

```
public class RadixSort {
        public static void radixSort(String[] a, int w) {
            //throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            // read LSD decimal digits or letter
            StringBuilder aux = new StringBuilder();
            int i = 0, j = w - 1;
            while (i < a.length) {
                char pointer;
                pointer = a[i++].charAt(j);
                aux.append(pointer);
            }
    
            // count occurrences of LSD decimal digits or letters and stores in frequency array (f)
            String d = new String(aux);
            int[] f = new int[('9' - '0' + 1) + ('z' - 'a' + 1)];
            int character;
            for (int k = 0; k < d.length(); k++) {
                character = d.charAt(k);
                if (character >= '0' && character <= '9') character -= '0';
                else if (character >= 'a' && character <= 'z') character -= 'W';
                f[character] += 1;
            }
    
            // calculate distribution of frequency array (f)
            for (int k = 0; k < f.length; k++) {
                if (k != f.length - 1)
                    f[k + 1] = f[k] + f[k + 1];
            }
    
            // calculate Sort array from last distribution array
            String[] s = new String[a.length];
            int index = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < f.length; k++) {
                if (d.charAt(index) - '0' == k) {
                    f[k] = f[k] - 1;
                    index++;
                }
            }
        }
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String[] a = {"461", "852", "211", "108"};
            radixSort(a, 3);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Key point: After calculating distribution of freqeuncy array, `f[i]` has number of strings which has digit that is less than or equal to `i`. Let's say we have to sort "461", "852", "211", "108" and we are currently looking to least significant digit. Then `f[1] == 2` ("46**1**", "21**1**"), `f[2] == 3` ("46**1**", 85**2**", "21**1**"), and `f[8] == 4` ("46**1**", 85**2**", "21**1**", "10**8**"). Therefore, in the sorted array, strings which has digit of `i` should be `f[i-1] + 1`th ~ `f[i]`th element in the sorted array.

There are two ways to implement this.

1. Look string from forwards, put string which has digit of `i` into `f[i-1] + 1`th element of sorted array, and then increment `f[i-1]`. (for 0, `f[-1] = 0`)
2. Look string from backwards, put string which has digit of `i` into `f[i]`th element of sorted array, and then decrement `f[i]`.

I'll use the second approach because I don't want to handle 0.

```java
public class RadixSort {
    public static void radixSort(String[] a, int w) {
        // sort finished if w == 0
        if (w == 0) {
            return;
        }

        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        ///////////////// SAME CODE FROM HERE ////////////////////////
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        // read LSD decimal digits or letter
        StringBuilder aux = new StringBuilder();
        int i = 0, j = w - 1;
        while (i < a.length) {
            char pointer;
            pointer = a[i++].charAt(j);
            aux.append(pointer);
        }

        // count occurrences of LSD decimal digits or letters and stores in frequency array (f)
        String d = new String(aux);
        int[] f = new int[('9' - '0' + 1) + ('z' - 'a' + 1)];
        int character;
        for (int k = 0; k < d.length(); k++) {
            character = d.charAt(k);
            if (character >= '0' && character <= '9') character -= '0';
            else if (character >= 'a' && character <= 'z') character -= 'W';
            f[character] += 1;
        }

        // calculate distribution of frequency array (f)
        for (int k = 0; k < f.length; k++) {
            if (k != f.length - 1)
                f[k + 1] = f[k] + f[k + 1];
        }
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        ///////////////// SAME CODE UNTIL HERE ///////////////////////
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        // calculate Sort array from last distribution array
        // s is the Sort array
        String[] s = new String[a.length];
        for (int k = d.length() - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
            // get the last character
            int digit = d.charAt(k);

            // convert to index of f array
            if (digit >= '0' && digit <= '9') digit -= '0';
            else if (digit >= 'a' && digit <= 'z') digit -= 'W';

            // this string should be "f[digit]th" string, that means the index is "f[digit] - 1"
            --f[digit];
            s[f[digit]] = a[k];
        }

        // copy Sort array to original array
        System.arraycopy(s, 0, a, 0, a.length);

        // sort next digit
        radixSort(a, w - 1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] a = {"461", "852", "211", "108"};
        radixSort(a, 3);

        // String.join for pretty output
        System.out.println(String.join(" ", a));
    }
}
```